# Pass value from one page to another in PHP without using URL

Tags: php, get, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I used to pass value from one page to another using session. E.g

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["id"];
?>
```

But for the following case i don't know how can i pass the id to the next page. This code is used to display group of people and the action column have an option to view the people details.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    $DBSystemAccess = dbSelectByWhere("SystemAccess", "", "ORDER By Timestamp");
    while ($SystemAccessDB = dbFetchArray($DBSystemAccess)) {
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <?php
            echo '<td>' . dbGroupNamebyId($_SESSION['PI_ID']) . '</td>';                
            echo '<td>' . $Status . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $SystemAccessDB['timeStamp'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . '<a href="adetails.php?ID=' . $SystemAccessDB['id'] . '" >View</a> </td>'
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

How can i replace `<a href="adetails.php?ID=' . $SystemAccessDB['id'] . '" >View</a>` to not showing ID in the URL?

Comment: can you convert your <a> tag to <button> ?

Comment: a `$_SESSION` array containing the ids, you would pass the array index in the url instead of ids ? a `$_POST` form with a hidden input (`type="hidden"`) containing the id ? If it fits your need I can make it an answer..

Comment: What's the reason for this? Is it purely aesthetics or are there security implications?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Taking the ID out of the URL probably isn't a good solution to the real problem.

Comment: Main reason for taking out id is security.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this with the hyper link it is not possible to hide the GET data.We need to use POST method.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    $DBSystemAccess = dbSelectByWhere("SystemAccess", "", "ORDER By Timestamp");
    while ($SystemAccessDB = dbFetchArray($DBSystemAccess)) {
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <?php
            echo '<td>' . dbGroupNamebyId($_SESSION['PI_ID']) . '</td>';                
            echo '<td>' . $Status . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $SystemAccessDB['timeStamp'] . '</td>';
            echo '<form name="test" method="post" action="testing.php">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="'.$SystemAccessDB['id'].'"/>';
            echo '<button type="submit">View</button>';
            echo '</form>';
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

When you will click it will redirect to testing.php with hidden value 'hidden_name' on which you can further query according to that value.

Comment: why down vote if any person having issue in particular scenario and we dig and found solution for this then where is the issue. Please give explanation once you down vote any one.

Comment: I didn't down vote. The problem with your answer is that you failed to understand that hiding the ID is likely not going to solve the OP's problem. Besides, putting it in a hidden element will only prevent those from seeing it who cannot do right click + inspect.